# Orientation change in Fragment. Restoring view state

Tags: android, fragment, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I have a fragment, which hold some `EditTexts`, some `RadioGroups` and `Spinners`.

When I change the orientation the view state isn't retained.
 I tried to override `onSavaInstanceState` and call `setRetainInstance(true)`, but it doesn't helped.

I also tried to save all inserted values in the `Bundle outState` like this: `outState.putString("name", mName.getText().toString())` and restore it in `onCreateView`.

Doesn't helped either, the `Bundle outState` in `onCreateView` hold the values, but I can't manipulate the views to set the value to it. For example like this: `mName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"))`

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by  "I can't manipulate the views" ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: Nope. It just wasn't working. I noticed, these behaviour was because I replaced the old Fragment in the FragmentActivity.

Comment: on Orientation you get a new instance of the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I had replaced the `Fragment` in the `FragmentActivity`, this caused tha fact that the state wasn't restored properly.

I surrounded the `Fragment` committing with `if (savedInstanceState == null)` in the `onCreate` method. 
Also I used the `Bundle outState` and `onSaveInstanceState` of the `Fragment` to restore the state in tha same `Fragment` properly.

Comment: Code would definitly be appreciated.